# Need config.ru to Start up a Sinatra App from within a Docker Container?

Tags: ruby, docker, containers, sinatra, rack

Why isn't the simple command `ruby my app.rb` working to boot up my Sinatra application from within a Docker container?

I have a very simple Sinatra app:

```
# myapp.rb

require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  'Hello world!'
end
```

I run this locally with `ruby myapp.rb` and I get the following output

```
== Sinatra (v2.1.0) has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from Puma
Puma starting in single mode...
* Puma version: 5.1.1 (ruby 2.7.0-p0) ("At Your Service")
*  Min threads: 0
*  Max threads: 5
*  Environment: development
*          PID: 49242
* Listening on http://127.0.0.1:4567
* Listening on http://[::1]:4567
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

Opens up on http://127.0.0.1:4567 with no issue. When moving to Dockerize the app, I create a Gemfile with Sinatra and the following Dockerfile.

```
FROM ruby:2.7.0

WORKDIR /code
COPY . /code
RUN bundle install

CMD ["ruby", "myapp.rb"]
```

Standing up the container, it seem successful (Docker Desktop is green, no terminal errors), but clicking on the suggested link http://localhost:4567/ doesn't load (sad Chrome face). Logs from within the container look like so

```
[2020-12-27 18:04:52] INFO WEBrick 1.6.0
[2020-12-27 18:04:52] INFO ruby 2.7.0 (2019-12-25) [x86_64-linux]
== Sinatra (v2.1.0) has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from WEBrick
[2020-12-27 18:04:52] INFO WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=1 port=4567
```

However, when I add the below config.ru file and change the last line of my Dockerfile to `CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rackup", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "-p", "4567"]`, http://localhost:4567/ opens with no issue.

```
# config.ru

require './myapp'
    
run Sinatra::Application
```

**Why are these tweaks necessary to make the app work?** The logs from with the container look nearly the same.

```
[2020-12-27 18:01:49] INFO WEBrick 1.6.0
[2020-12-27 18:01:49] INFO ruby 2.7.0 (2019-12-25) [x86_64-linux]
[2020-12-27 18:01:49] INFO WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=1 port=4567
172.17.0.1 - - [27/Dec/2020:18:02:44 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12 0.0420
```

I'm not necessarily wondering about "best practices" here (this is a side project). I'm more just trying to understand what I might be missing about how Dockerizing apps works.

Docker commands for both cases (and I clear the images/containers between runs):

```
docker build --tag sinatra-img .
docker run --name sinatra-app -dp 4567:4567 sinatra-img
```

Comment: Are you sure your code is running? Did you install Sinatra and dependencies into your container? If you did, maybe Ruby isn't in the container's PATH, your container doesn't have a web server, or the web server in use is binding to a different port. Maybe check the container's process list and open ports.

Comment: Sinatra should be installed via the Gemfile (added it above for clarity). I didn't see any errors upon build, so I assume any dependencies it might have should be installed.

Comment: I believe the code should be running. The container logs show `[2020-12-22 21:45:21] INFO ruby 2.7.0 (2019-12-25) [x86_64-linux]
== Sinatra (v2.1.0) has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from WEBrick
[2020-12-22 21:45:21] INFO WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=8 port=4567`

Comment: Curiously I don't see pid=8 when I run ps from the CLI. I only see an "sh" and my own ps search.

Comment: Have you tried visiting "http:// localhost:4567" instead?

Comment: @engineersmnky unfortunately yes. I get the sad chrome logo.

Comment: Edited the question to detail some of the questions you all asked

Comment: If you don’t run `bundle exec` you aren’t going to have access to bundled gems. This often confuses people when they install system or ruby environment gems locally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you start your app with `ruby myapp.rb` in a Docker container, your app  is listening on `localhost` because it is running in development mode. If your Docker server runs in a VM, you won't be able to access your app. To fix this, when you run your app in a Docker container, make sure that it is listening on 0.0.0.0: `ruby myapp.rb -o 0.0.0.0`

Comment: Interesting! As expected, that command works both locally and in my Dockerfile. Locally my app opens up on http://0.0.0.0:4567 and from Docker desktop http://localhost:4567. What is it about specifying the -o 0.0.0.0 that allows this to work? The logs from within the container look exactly the same to the ruby myapp.rb Docker case, yet it opens.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by running my Docker server in a VM. I'm just doing docker desktop here and local.

Comment: Docker uses a Virtual Machine behind the scenes on some systems, like Macs. Binding to `0.0.0.0` means that your app will listen for connections from everywhere, instead of just local connections from inside the VM. The networking concepts behind `0.0.0.0` is explained here: https://superuser.com/questions/949428/whats-the-difference-between-127-0-0-1-and-0-0-0-0

Comment: Docker uses its own network stack unless you specify `--net host`. In addition to that, it runs in a VM on certain platforms.

Comment: Awesome! I'll poke a little more into this later. Some resources I'm bookmarking (in case anyone else is looking into this): 1 - Docker Connection refused https://pythonspeed.com/articles/docker-connection-refused/, 2 - Container localhost port mapping - https://forums.docker.com/t/cant-connect-to-container-on-localhost-with-port-mapping/52716, 3 - Container networking - https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/, 4 - Sinatra docs -o http://sinatrarb.com/configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**:

The following answer relates to a previous version of the question. The new question has a different answer (fixing the binding address using the `-o 0.0.0.0` CLI argument).

---

The Sinatra framework is based on Rack and requires a Rack compatible server... either that, or it can also fallback on the WEBrick server that's included with the Ruby language bundle.

WEBrick is a decent server, but it wasn't designed for the heavier loads or the needs of an actual web application running in production.

For this reason, you **SHOULD** use a Rack compatible server.

However, this does not mean that you have to use the `rackup` CLI helper.

Some servers, like Puma, iodine and passenger include their own CLI, so you could run your application using:

```
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "puma", "-p", "4567"]
```

Type `puma -h` (or `iodine -h`) for more command line options. A server's specific CLI might offer some server specific features you don't get with `backup`. For example, Iodine exposes some security options through it's CLI (maximum file upload size, maximum total header length, web socket message limits, etc').

**Using the server's CLI interface should be considered a better option**.

In addition, although I wouldn't recommend it, some servers also provide a Ruby API that allows you start the server from a Ruby script (instead of a `config.ru` file). i.e., with iodine (I'm biased):

```
ENV['PORT'] ||= "4567"
require 'iodine' # will test the `ENV['PORT']` value

require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  'Hello world!'
end

Iodine.listen service: :http, public: './public', handler: Sinatra::Application
# Iodine.threads = 16 # or whatever.
# Iodine.workers = -2 # half the core count (negative value).
Iodine.start
```

I wouldn't use this approach. It tends to be more fragile and it also hardcodes both the environment and the server settings in the application.

I would just add the `config.ru` and use a decent server (I like iodine, but Puma is much more popular and unless you need real-time pub/sub, websockets or some specific security/performance features, popular is often safer).

---

**EDIT** (according to comment):

If what you're really looking for is to embed the command `bundle exec` into the Ruby script (for version control using a `gemfile`), you can start the script with the lines

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require
```

Or, if you don't want to use a `gemfile` at all (or don't require version control), you can jus start the first line with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

Then you can start your server directly:

```
CMD ["puma", "-p", "4567"]
```

Or, without using the server's CLI, using the example script above, run:

```
CMD ["my_script.rb"]
```

Comment: Thank you for the info! I'm not necessarily looking for a best practices answer here (this is a side project and I'm not concerned about scale), but rather why running `ruby myapp.rb` from within the container doesn't work and you seem to need the bundle exec ... way to start it up.

Comment: @stk1234 `bundle exec` loads all the gems from the gem file and locks you to the versions in the `gemfile.lock` before running the command that comes after the word `exec`. You don't have to use bundler, but it does make version control much easier.

Comment: @stk1234 - I updated to answer to provide these additional variations.